# Mongodb group by select nonexistent column

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am a MongoDB novice. I am trying to group data from a document, which works. But I now want to add a column with static data in it.

For example, I could write something like this in SQL.

```
select e.dptId, count(e.empId), 'foo' as foo
from employee e
group by e.dptId, 'foo'
```

I have tried this,

```
db.employee.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: { dptId: '$dptId', foo: 'foo' }, 
        empCount: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
);
```

which gives me "exception: field path references must be prefixed with a '$'. I cant prefix it with $, as that would be a field reference.

I have also tried this,

```
db.employee.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: { dptId: '$dptId' }, 
        empCount: { $sum: 1 },
        foo: 'foo'
    }}
);
```

which gives me "exception: the group aggregate field 'temp' must be defined as an expression inside an object".

I have tried playing with braces, without braces (as shown) etc. Still no luck. Is it even possible in mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick would be to conditionally assign a value with the `$ifNull` operator:

```
db.employee.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: { dptId: '$dptId', 
               foo: { $ifNull: ['$foo', 'foo'] }
             }, 
        empCount: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
);
```

Above, it just looks for a field called `foo` and if it's not present, sets the `foo` grouped field to the value of `foo`. You could change the field MongoDB checks for as well.

You may be able to use `$concat` as well to get your desired outcome:

```
db.employee.aggregate( 
{ $group : { 
    _id : { dptId: '$dptId', 
            foo: { $concat : [ "foo" ] }
          },
    empCount: { $sum: 1 }
}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The first one, where we try to make it part of _id, fails with 'Unexpected token }' even though I have copied and re-verified the script over and over. All the { and } are matching up. If I remove the foo part, it works properly. As for concat, I cant use it, as its not part of group operator.

Comment: `$concat` definitely can work with $group. I expanded the code.

Comment: Also -- I'd accidentally left out the `[` and `]` array markers for the `$isNull` when I typed in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much. They both worked!!! The square brackets helped. As for the concat, I was trying to do that outside of the _id field. Coming from sql background, I should've known it should be within the id field. Duh!